# How to avoid my advisor as a reference?

Tags: advisor, application, interpersonal-issues

I had a bad relationship with my advisor. He told me evidently that he won’t write the recommendation letter for me in the future.

Of course, I will not put him in my reference list in my future career. But I don’t know if the future employer will contact him or question my working performance or attitude? I feel very bad about this. Can you guys give me some suggestions?

Comment: Are you applying for academic jobs, or jobs in industry?

Comment: Do you have sufficient (two or three) other people you worked that are willing to act as a reference and able to write you a letter of recommendation if requested?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.I worked in industry now, and I don't have any plan to apply for the academic jobs in the future.

Comment: "I don’t dare to look for other better opportunities due to this issue. " Why? What other option have? Falling out of work or stacking in a place you shouldn't is much worse solution.

Comment: Just to clear things up: you work now at industry and by postdoc supervisor you refer to the supervisor or a previous academic job? And you are looking for job in industry now? Do you need academic recommendation letters for an industrial job at all? Esp that you already have industrial experience.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about applying for jobs outside academia.

Comment: Your problem may be on-topic on [workplace.se] though; please check [their guidelines](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in my mind. The first is not having the post doc supervisor as a reference. As you get further along in your career, you will have to leave someone that knows you well off your list of references. If you can develop a strong enough network that you have 3-5 people who know you and your work well and are willing to write you strong letter, then the absence of your post doc supervisor will not be seen s odd.

The second issue is more problematic and that is if your post doc advisor is contacted informally, he may actively or inactively sabotage you. In order to get around this, you need to repair the relationship, such that it is not a problem. As a first step, make sure that he is really unwilling to be a reference. If that is the case, then make it clear that you will not use him as a reference. Ask him if he is willing to tactfully deflect informal enquires. If he is, and you believe him, that you do not have much to worry about. If not, consider having one of your letter writers address the issues you have with you post doc supervisor.

Having a reference point out bad things is always dangerous in that it makes the hiring committee aware of something they might not find out about. The advantage is it is the only way to really get your side of the story told. It is worth talking to your other references about how to address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a viable substitute, there probably won't be much fuss about it. I am talking about the case of still being able to churn out a decent list of academic references, having the requisite number (whatever that may be), who are all safe choices (*so to speak*), i.e. can be trusted to put in a good word for you.

If that is not the case, the situation can get comparatively tricky if your apprehensions about people contacting him turn out to be true. In that cases, it always appears safer to leave him out, but I think the best strategy would be to not make any *a priori* assumptions. He might have said what he said in a fit of rage when he was extremely pissed off over something, and that anger may have abated later. I'm sure he knows how a bad recommendation can adversely affect your career, so while he may not give you a very strongly favorable recommendation, he may settle for a more subdued form of the same as a safe and neutral stance. (Like a brief letter just saying you are good, and no real supporting details or instances where he found you good to back it up. This won't really count as something prospective employers would count a strong point in your favor, but it still does count as a positive recommendation.) I would say, it is always best to ask him explicitly. Write him a polite email, saying something like the following:

> ... while it is true that our association didn't really work out (for whatever reasons), a favorable recommendation from a person I've previously worked with is still valuable for my career.
>   ... Please let me know whether it would be acceptable to you if I include your name in the list of academic references in applications for my further endeavors.

A short, positive response to this shall serve your purpose - include him then. Negative rants of why you are so pathetic also clears the air - leave him out. No response to this email means he's too pissed or too busy. In the former case, you can surely leave him out, in the latter case, things are indeterminate - you can't be sure either way. The safest bet then is to leave him out.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score -1):

There is not much you can do to prevent anyone from talking to your postdoc advisor, particularly if they do so informally as part of the hiring process. This is sometimes frowned upon by HR departments, but there is not much that can be done about informal questions like "What do you think about ZZZ's potential?", which could be asked in person at a conference.

For certain types of applications, you can list people who you would *not* like to review you. This is often true for grant applications and tenure applications, in my experience, but not for job applications.

The safest advice is just to not mention anything about your advisor in your job application and hope for the best. It could be more dangerous for your application to suggest that you do not get along with people, than to try to explain why you don't get along with your advisor.

If you absolutely cannot bear to do that, one option is to talk to another reference writer who you know well, and ask them to mention it very discreetly in their letter.

(The OP has clarified that they are applying for positions in industry. This answer was written more from the perspective of academic job applications. I have never applied to jobs in industry, so I cannot speak to them.)